# How to show something for a very brief and precise amount of time

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, web

I am developing a very game-like web application, and there is a particular requirement that is driving me nuts: I have to show an image for a very short (some hundreds of ms, sometimes even just 25ms, just enough for the user to perceive *something* when he/she already knows what to look for). This application has to work on Chrome, Firefox and IE9+, but also Android tablets and iPad.

The only reliable way of doing this in desktop browsers I have found is Flash. Using Javascript and html5 canvas in a lot of computers results in the items not even being rendered. On the other hand, Flash doesn't work on the iPad and some Androids, but in those devices, our tests show, the javascript way seems to work just fine. So this is the best solution I have found: grosso modo, `if iPad then load_javascript_version() else load_flash_version()`.

Have you seen anything like this done before? Should I abandon any hope of finding a more maintainable solution?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: javascript in browser is inherently single threaded, this means that the currently executing thing gets to run to completion. IE timing stuff is never guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried this particular use case, but a [2D library](http://www.jsdb.io/images/2d-graphics/?sort=rating) like [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/) should be able to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are jQuery functions like timeout: http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/ and delay: http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using RequestAnimationFrame in your game loop? If not please read about it  and ensure that your image is preloaded when you try to render it.

[Mozilla dev RAF api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Most devices and browsers that have hardware accelerated canvas support, should be able to achive as fast as 60 fps fairly, which means you would be able to show an image for a single frame or about 16.7 ms.

I have managed to do similar things using the createjs library which can very easily be set to use the RequestAnimationFrame api.

[Createjs ticker RAF](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Ticker.html#property_RAF)